# Access nested items in CollectionViewGroup

Tags: c#, wpf

So i am trying to access some nested items in a CollectionView then bind them to a ListBox. Is there a simple way to do this? At the moment my ListBox is binding to "ContactListName" which is the immediate item but I would like to bind to "LabelName" which is a nested item of ContactList. Thanks - Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting DisplayMemberPath for ListBox

```
tagsList.ItemsSource = contactsList.SelectedItems;
tagsList.DisplayMemberPath = "LabelName";
```

if you are using ItemTemplate You need to set Binding

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TagsTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelName, Mode=Default}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToFontSizeConverter}, Mode=Default}" Foreground="#FF0D0AF7"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I got an InvalidOperationException - Cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate.

Comment: check the edited code.. will be helpful if you post your xaml

Comment: You dont need to set the DisplayMemberPath if you set ItemTemplate Binding

Comment: Yeah when i removed this nothing was displayed. It does not seem to know where to look for "LabelName"